# How would this piece of C# code be converted to C version of it?

Tags: c#, c

> So I am trying to have this exact code but in C, what I am struggling with is the 'ref' and 'out' part of the code.

```
private static void FixItUp(ref byte first, ref byte second, out byte output)
    {
        //d3d2d1d0p2p1p0
        //p2 - d3d2d1
        //p1 - d3d1d0
        //p0 - d2d1d0
        FixNibble(ref first);
        FixNibble(ref second);

        output = (byte)((byte)(first >> 3 & 0b00001111) | (byte)(second << 1 & 0b11110000));
    }
```

Comment: There's a moderate chance that `byte` in C# matches `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.  The `out` in C# would correspond to a pointer in C.  I've not studied C# so I don't know the implications of the `ref`, either in the function interface or the calls to `FixNibble()`.   You'd use `*output` in the assignment.  What else you'd need depends on the `FixNibble()` function and the meaning of `ref`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't know much C but I believe both `ref` and `out` would correspond to pointers in C. `out` just tells the compiler that the object needs to be initialized inside the method while `ref` means it should be already initialized. I don't think that distinction exists in C?

Comment: Yes, the byte equivalent in C is uint8_t.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed — no, there isn't a way in C to distinguish between "initialized by the caller, used as pointer here" and "pointer needs to be assigned by called code".  The nearest is to use a `const` qualifier, but it isn't satisfactory.  I won't be surprised to find that `ref` does mean "pass as pointer", but I'm not sure about why it's present in the call to `FixNibble()` — it likely means that whatever changes are made by `FixNibble()` will be reflected in both `FixItUp()` and the code that calls it.  But I'm not a C# coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For `first` and `second` to be passed to `FixNibble` as shown, they will likely have to be pointers since C doesn't pass by reference. This assuming `FixNibble` is something like `void FixNibble(uint8_t*);`. However, it would be more sensible to pass them by value to the `FixItUp` function.
- `output` must also be a pointer in order to return the result through it.
- C does not support binary integer constants so those must be converted to hex. Always use unsigned constants when doing bitwise operations.
- C contains various dangerous implicit promotion rules that must be dodged before bit-shifting. The easiest way to do this is to convert to a large integer type such as `uint32_t`.
- Readability: use extra parenthesis to self-document operator precedence order. We can make the expression more readable by splitting it in several lines.

---

```
#include <stdint.h>

static void FixItUp (uint8_t first, uint8_t second, uint8_t* output)
{
  FixNibble(&first);
  FixNibble(&second);

  first   = ((uint32_t)first  >> 3) & 0x0Fu;
  second  = ((uint32_t)second << 1) & 0xF0u;
  *output = first | second;
}
```

Or use the equivalent pedantic/MISRA-C compliant version:

```
#include <stdint.h>

static void FixItUp (uint8_t first, uint8_t second, uint8_t* output)
{
  FixNibble(&first);
  FixNibble(&second);

  first   = (uint8_t) ( ((uint32_t)first  >> 3) & 0x0Fu );
  second  = (uint8_t) ( ((uint32_t)second << 1) & 0xF0u );
  *output = (uint8_t) (first | second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to read [how C pass arguments to function](https://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/) and docs of [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) and [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

```
void FixItUp(uint8_t* first, uint8_t* second, uint8_t* output)
    {
        FixNibble(first);
        FixNibble(second);

        *output = (((*first) >> 3 & 0b00001111) | ((*second) << 1 & 0b11110000));
    }
```

so your C code should look something like this, you should pass references to function `FixNibble` , but you should use values of your arguments to count `output`, also please note difference between `ref` and `out` 
**Out is like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be initialized before it is passed**.

Comment: Thanks, it did the job. I will definitely spend some time reading on it.

Comment: Note that `0b00001111` is an extension to standard C (as in C11 or C18).  It is valid in C++14 and onward, and many C compilers support it as an extension.